# Filter by association in ruby on rails using active admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, model-associations

I have two models: Login and Account

```
class Login
  belongs_to :account
  attr_accessible: first_name, primary_admin # primary_admin is boolean
end

class Account
 has_many: logins

 def primary_admin
  @primary_admin ||= self.logins.find { |l| l.primary_admin }
 end
end
```

So in resume an Account has many Logins, but there is only one Login with **primary_admin = true**. In the filters of Account I want to search for that Login (the one with primary_admin = true) but using the first_name of the Login.

Using active admin in app/admin/account.rb I have something like this

```
filter :primary_admin, as: :string
```

But is obviously not working, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Here is the database schema:

**Login**

```
id             :integer(4)      not null, primary key
email          :string(255)     default(""), not null
first_name     :string(255)
last_name      :string(255)
primary_admin  :boolean(1)
account_id     :integer(4)
```

**Account**

```
id              :integer(4)      not null, primary key
name            :string(255)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if primary_admin is a string field

```
ActiveAdmin.register Account do
  filter :primary_admin, as: => :string
end

ActiveAdmin.register Login do
  filter :account_primary_admin, as: => :string
end
```

Or try this if primary_admin is a boolean field

```
ActiveAdmin.register Account do
  filter :primary_admin, :as => :select
end

ActiveAdmin.register Login do
  filter :account_primary_admin, :as => :select
end
```

and you might have to remove this

```
def primary_admin
  @primary_admin ||= self.logins.find { |l| l.primary_admin }
end
```

Comment: Hey, I just edited my question I think it was not clear, I tried those approaches that you mention but none of them are working. I want to search a Login with two attributes using the first_name and primary_admin = true. I don't know if its possible, though

Comment: ok, added another suggestion. Maybe I dont get what you want. You want two filters or one filter for both primary_admin and first_name?

Comment: Yes I want one filter for both the primary_admin and first_name. Is there a way to mix in a filter both attributes primary_admin and first_name? I added to my question the database scheme for both tables Account and Login, I hope it would make things a little more clear

Comment: you could try to create a new db field that is auto-populated

after_commit{|model| update_column(:your_new_column, "#{first_name} #{primary_admin})}  

 with both columns or try to create a virtual

Comment: you could try to create a new db field that is auto-populated

after_commit{|model| update_column(:your_new_column, "#{first_name} #{primary_admin})}  

 with both columns or try to create a virtual column or view in your DB

Comment: Thanks James I think is not working because I have a "primary_admin" in the attributes and as a method, I'm going to talk to the database administrator about those approaches that you mention. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

More things you can try to find your primary_admin using filter buttons

```
#model/account.rb
scope :primary, where(:login_id => Login.where(:primary => true))

#admin/accounts.rb
scope :primary
```

or

```
#model/login.rb
scope :primary, where(:primary_admin => true)

#admin/logins.rb
scope :primary
```